# Having problem with creating a remove function

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following exer

Declare a function named remove_item.  It takes a list and an item parameters. It returns a list with the item removed from it

I create my function, i concatenate both list and now i have to remove the  parameter from a list, here is where i strugle

```
def remove_item(list1,*args):
    c=list1+list(args)
    for i in c:
       if i[x]=args[y]:
          
list1=['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Mango', 'Milk']

print(remove_item(list1,'Mango'))
```

Output:# ['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Milk'];

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't understand your thinking, this piece of code works. Simply check the words in *args and delete them from the list with `list1.remove(word)`:

```
list1=['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Mango', 'Milk']

def remove_item(list1, *args):
    for word in args:
        if word in list1:
            list1.remove(word)
    return list1

print(remove_item(list1, 'Mango'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, do you still need it as args?

```
def remove_item(list1,item):
    for i in list1:
       if i == item:
           list1.remove(i)
    return list1
          
list1=['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Mango', 'Milk']
print(remove_item(list1,'Mango'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
def remove_item(list1, *args):
    return [i for i in list1 if i not in args]

list1 = ['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Mango', 'Milk']    
print(remove_item(list1, 'Mango'))
```

OR if you need to return the same list that pass to the function you can do

```
def remove_item(list1, *args):
    for i in args:
        if i in list1:
            list1.remove(i)
    return list1
```

Both will return

```
['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Milk']
```

This will return a list without the arguments that pass to the function after the first argument that is the list.